# How to make Bootstrap buttons in separate forms inline (horizontally aligned)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the following Bootstrap buttons to be on the same horizontal line:

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg checkout" href="/foo/buy">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> $50.00
</a>

<form action="/subscriptions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> Watch
    </button>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="/foo/watchers">
      <span>1</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>

<form action="/wishlists" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i> Add to wishlist
    </button>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="/foo/wishlists">
      <span>1</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Here's a JSFiddle of it.](https://jsfiddle.net/r7dn8uax/1/)

I've tried adding using the `.form-horizontal` and `.form-inline` classes (although I suspect those are for intra-form styling), as well as doing `display: inline`, but can't seem to get it to work (I'm bad at CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
style="float:left; width: auto"
```

to your form selector